# Qt directory non-existent (pull the submodule?) Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I'm compiling this project: https://github.com/stenzek/duckstation using Visual Studio 2022 with the latest updates.

Everything seems to be compiled successfully but with only one error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Qt directory non-existent (pull the submodule?) duckstation-qt  C:\...\QtCompile.props  50
```

where is the problem? I'm new to c++ and QT.

Comment: `git clone --recursive` (as mentioned in the readme) should have downloaded the required submodules as well.

Comment: @Fareanor I did that but no success.